# QT: ssl https craches my dll, throws IniterrorSystem.DllNotFoundException

Tags: qt, dll, ssl

I've created a simple dll in qt which starts up a new thread and handles different network request with the QNetworkAccessManager. Working with ordinary HTTP requests works fine but I've gotten some problems when trying to start using HTTPS instead.

I've installed openssl and configured qt to use it with:
-openssl -I C:\OpenSSL\include -L C:\OpenSSL\lib

I can compile the dll but when I try to access the dll from my application I get a IniterrorSystem.DllNotFoundException.
This error appears as soon as I try to use the QSslSocket class, for example I'm just trying to initiate a variable.

QSslSocket socket;
With this initiation the dll crashes with the above error.

//QSslSocket socket;
removing the init will let the dll continue but the https request doesn't work and I don't get any error message from the QNetworkAccessManager. I tried connecting to the sslError signal but that never happens as well.

I've put the dlls "libeay32.dll", "libssl32.dll" & "ssleay32.dll" in the same folder as my dll and have OpenSSL successfully installed.

Anyone have any Idea what I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the [Visual C++ Runtime Libraries](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30679) installed? OpenSSL depends on the **msvcr** dll on Windows.

Comment: yes I do have that. The thing is that when I run the https in an other application that works similar to my dll the ssl works, the only difference is that I've compiled the application with MinGW and the dll is compiled using msvc2010 x64.I searched my computer for the msvcr file and it was found.

Comment: Try using [Dependency Walker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) on your dll to see what the missing dependencies are. Also maybe it's a better idea to build both using either MinGW or MSVC? You have the option to do that in QtCreator.